# Number of linear independent eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider matrix A n*n with rank r and m distinct eigenvalues.
I know that there is an independent eigenvector corresponds to each eigenvalues.
Is it possible to have more independent eigenvectors than distinct eigenvalues?
In general case is there any relation between n , r and m and number of independent eigenvectors?

Answer (score 2):

The only general result is this: the eigenvalues of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ are the roots of its *characteristic polynomial* $\det(A-tI)$, which has degree $n$, so there are $m\le n$ distinct real or complex eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m$, each with *algebraic multiplicity* $r_i$, and of course
$$r_1+\dots+r_m=n.$$
On the other hand, to each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ there corresponds an eigenspace $E_{\lambda_i}$. The dimensions of eigenspaces are called the *geometric multiplicities* of the eigenvalues, and they satisfy the inequalities
$$1\le \dim E_{\lambda_i}\le r_i\qquad(i=1,\dots,m).$$
A necessary and sufficient condition for a matrix to be diagonalisable is that the geometric multiplicity of each eigenvalue be equal to its algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: so for example is it possible for a 10 by 10 matrix that have 5 distinct eigenvalues, have 8  independent eigenvectores?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.